# Lots of variability in the effective sample size but stable parameter estimates?

Tags: markov-process, pymc, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I ran 4 chains with [NUTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246) and made a forest plot, but I cannot show the plot here. In words, what I am seeing is the there is a lot of variability in the effective sample size (ESS) in the chains. Across the 30ish parameters it almost looks like the ESS is uniform. One chain might have less than 100 ESS while another has 750 or more for the same parameter.

And yet the parameter estimates themselves are very consistent across chains.

A large ESS suggests very little autocorrelation along a chain. So if I am getting very consistent estimates for a parameter regardless of whether the ESS is high or low, it seems that the sort of autocorrelation that is occurring in my chains is not affecting my sampling.

Is this a known problem in troubleshooting model estimated with NUTS? I've been reading [Gelman *et al* 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808) on Bayesian workflow, but I have not gotten any particular insights about this case.